# creating row total in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, cumulative-sum

Being quite new on R, i would like to create a row "total" with the sum of the lines of each column, for the columns "nb de sejours" and "activite en valeur" (for each year). Could anyone help me ?

> dput(head(computing))

```
structure(list(000), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried the following, without success :

```
computing %>%
  group_by(`trip`) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(as.numeric('trip N2')))
```

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should avoid having spaces in column names. Moreover, using `sum(as.numeric(\`nb de sejours N2\`))` should fix the issue.

Comment: (1) When there are warnings/errors with your code, while they might not mean a lot to you, they are still relevant. Include the literal warning/error text in your questions. (2) In R, non-compliant variable names like these need to be referenced using backticks, never single-quotes. The latter _always_ produce strings, the former works. Use `summarise(total = sum(as.numeric(\`nb de sejours N2\`)))`

Comment: Are you trying to sum one column or all columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to convert numeric columns from characters to numeric first, then we use `adorn_totals()` from package `janitor`

```
fra_computing %>% mutate(across(-c("type de sejour"), as.numeric)) %>% adorn_totals("row")

type de sejour nb de sejours N2 annee N2 nb de sejours N1 annee N1 nb de sejours N annee N activite en valeur N2
   Ambulatoires             5774     2019             4689     2020            5944    2021             566.41150
       Externes                7     2019                0     2020               2    2021              10.28571
    Hospitalisé             9478     2019             7362     2020            7502    2021            2409.20004
        Séances               86     2019                9     2020               3    2021             197.40698
          Total            15345     8076            12060     8080           13451    8084            3183.30423
 activite en valeur N1 activite en valeur N
              623.2261             712.3407
                   NaN              24.0000
             2507.3627            2728.7683
              188.7778             202.3333
             3319.3665            3667.4423
```

Comment: this is perfect, thanks ! i also would like to create a function calculating the price and volume effects (as described here https://learnaccountingfinance.com/2018/11/21/sales-variances/), for instance price effect from N-1 to N : ("activite en valeur N" - "activite en valeur N1")/"nb de sejours N", do you know the function to use to repeat that for each year (and put it in a new row ?)